# Does any one have fresh setup of Angular 4 + Laravel 5.3

Tags: angular, laravel-5.3

I am new to angular 4 and Laravel 5.3, i wanted a fresh setup of laravel 5.3 + angular 4.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To start with Angular, you first need NodeJS and [Angular-CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki) installed. NOTE: NodeJS will install also the prerequisite *npm*.

After that, open the CMD and type the following:

```
> ng new my-project-name

>//let it install

> cd my-project-name
```

The tool will automatically install Angular 4 on *my-project-name*.

To get started with Angular-CLI, follow documentation on the [Angular-CLI] link above.

For Laravel, you will need [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) first and the following:

- PHP >= 5.6.4
- OpenSSL PHP Extension
- PDO PHP Extension
- Mbstring PHP Extension
- Tokenizer PHP Extension
- XML PHP Extension

Once you're done with the above, open CMD and type the following:

```
>composer global require "laravel/installer"

>//let it install

>laravel new folder_name`
```

For more information visit Laravel Official Documentation on Laravel website.

Comment: I am done with setup i am using Laravel 5.3, Angular 4 and i want to implement lazy loading, how should i do.